# What is the most efficient way to clear an array-based stack in Java for speed and memory efficiency?

Tags: java, arrays, performance

```java
public class ArrayBasedStack<T> implements StackInterface<T> {

    private static final int INITIAL_CAPACITY = 5;

    private T[] data;
    private int topOfStack;

    public ArrayBasedStack() {
        this(INITIAL_CAPACITY);
    }

    public ArrayBasedStack(int capacity) {
        if (capacity <= 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Array initial size error.");

        this.data = (T[]) new Object[capacity];
        this.topOfStack = -1;
    }

    @Override
    public void push(T newEntry) {
        if (isArrayFull()) expandArray();
        data[++topOfStack] = newEntry;
    }

    @Override
    public T pop() {
        if (isEmpty()) throw new EmptyStackException();
        T item = data[topOfStack];
        data[topOfStack--] = null;
        return item;
    }

    @Override
    public T peek() {
        if (isEmpty()) throw new EmptyStackException();
        return data[topOfStack];
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return topOfStack < 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {}

    private void expandArray() {
        int doubledSizeOfData = data.length * 2;
        data = Arrays.copyOf(data, doubledSizeOfData);
    }

    private boolean isArrayFull() {
        return topOfStack >= data.length - 1;
    }
}
```

So I have this code above. I see three ways of implementing the `clear` method.

1. Set the `topOfStack` field to be -1.
2. Reallocate the array.
3. Set all the values to be null.

So my question is what would be the best way to clear a Stack. Maybe there is no "right" answer but rather what is more important to me; speed or memory efficiency.

Comment: Set your ArrayBasedStack object to null and let garbage collection deal with it?

Comment: It depends on your assumptions about the future of the stack.  If it's going to 'soon' hold as many elements as it has been holding, then leave it allocated, and just reset the top of stack.  There's no point *as far as stack operation is concerned* in setting elements to null, since they're logically 'not in the empty stack' and thus cannot be seen.  But in Java it might be useful to get the previous contents to be garbage-collectable.

Comment: It will also depend on how many cells of the array need to be reinitialized.  But you are most likely doing *premature optimization* here; i.e. wasting **precious developer time** on performance that ultimately doesn't matter.   On the off-chance that this actually matters ... you should do some profiling and benchmarking of your entire application to determine which strategy works best ... in context.